# Magento2 how to get web image in controller file inside?

Tags: magento2, error, controllers, image-url

I am using `magneto2` and in controller file I try to call `getImageUrl` function but unable to get Image url. 
Please let me know how to get products image url in controller.
In console i an getting

```
500 request error
```

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: What says webserver log?

Answer (score 0):

The way you can get image file in controller or in any class, you have to inject  `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory` dependency into constructor of that class first.Like following

```
protected $_productRepositoryFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory $productRepositoryFactory
) {

    $this->_productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
}
```

Now you can get images like following:

```
$product = $this->_productRepositoryFactory->create()->getById($item->getProductId());
$product->getData('image');
$product->getData('thumbnail');
$product->getData('small_image');
```

You will get images dir path you can append base media url before it to render.